# Display 3 items per row in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm trying to show 3 items per row in collection view but it always shows 2 items. I've read few tutorials on this topic but can't figure out what else I need to do. Is there something missing in storyboard? How to fix it?

```
extension HomeViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath ) -> CGSize {

        let widthPerItem = collectionView.bounds.width/3.0

        return CGSize(width: widthPerItem, height: widthPerItem)
    }

  func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {

        return UIEdgeInsets.zero
  }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you set collectionView estimate size to none?

Comment: Yes, just figured it out. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably, you must not be setting the `minimumInteritemSpacing` of collection view.

**Storyboards:**
Goto storyboard and select your collection view. In attributes or scale tab, you will see Min Spacing set that to 0 in order to display 3 cells with no spacing.

**Programatically:**

```
let obj = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
          obj.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
          obj.minimumLineSpacing = 0
```

then instantiate the UICollectionView with above layout.

Moreover, You are dividing your collection view width by 3, means you don't want any spacing between cells (if you want some space, multiply spacing by 2, subtract from width and then divide by 3).